# How to solve: "ValueError: Validation size should be between 0 and 0. Received: 5000."?

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

I am trying to make a character recognition classifier for bangla alphabets. The images are size of 50x50. There are in total of 50 classes. Using the below CNN model to train but I am encountering this error: "ValueError: Validation size should be between 0 and 0. Received: 5000."
How do I resolve this?

**MODEL**

```js
# Python 3.6.0
# tensorflow 1.1.0

import os
import os.path as path

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.tools import freeze_graph
from tensorflow.python.tools import optimize_for_inference_lib

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

MODEL_NAME = 'mnist_convnet'
NUM_STEPS = 3000
BATCH_SIZE = 16

def model_input(input_node_name, keep_prob_node_name):
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 50*50], name=input_node_name)
    keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name=keep_prob_node_name)
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 50])
    return x, keep_prob, y_

def build_model(x, keep_prob, y_, output_node_name):
    x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 50, 50, 1])
    # 50*50*1

    conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(x_image, 64, 3, 1, 'same', activation=tf.nn.relu)
    # 50*50*64
    pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv1, 2, 2, 'same')
    # 14*14*64

    conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(pool1, 128, 3, 1, 'same', activation=tf.nn.relu)
    # 14*14*128
    pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv2, 2, 2, 'same')
    # 7*7*128

    conv3 = tf.layers.conv2d(pool2, 256, 3, 1, 'same', activation=tf.nn.relu)
    # 7*7*256
    pool3 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv3, 2, 2, 'same')
    # 4*4*256

    flatten = tf.reshape(pool3, [-1, 4*4*256])
    fc = tf.layers.dense(flatten, 1024, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    dropout = tf.nn.dropout(fc, keep_prob)
    logits = tf.layers.dense(dropout, 50)
    outputs = tf.nn.softmax(logits, name=output_node_name)

    # loss
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=logits))

    # train step
    train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(loss)

    # accuracy
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(outputs, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

    tf.summary.scalar("loss", loss)
    tf.summary.scalar("accuracy", accuracy)
    merged_summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()

    return train_step, loss, accuracy, merged_summary_op

def train(x, keep_prob, y_, train_step, loss, accuracy,
        merged_summary_op, saver):
    print("training start...")

    mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init_op)

        tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def, 'out',
            MODEL_NAME + '.pbtxt', True)

        # op to write logs to Tensorboard
        summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('logs/',
            graph=tf.get_default_graph())

        for step in range(NUM_STEPS):
            batch = mnist.train.next_batch(BATCH_SIZE)
            if step % 100 == 0:
                train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
                    x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
                print('step %d, training accuracy %f' % (step, train_accuracy))
            _, summary = sess.run([train_step, merged_summary_op],
                feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})
            summary_writer.add_summary(summary, step)

        saver.save(sess, 'out/' + MODEL_NAME + '.chkp')

        test_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images,
                                    y_: mnist.test.labels,
                                    keep_prob: 1.0})
        print('test accuracy %g' % test_accuracy)

    print("training finished!")

def export_model(input_node_names, output_node_name):
    freeze_graph.freeze_graph('out/' + MODEL_NAME + '.pbtxt', None, False,
        'out/' + MODEL_NAME + '.chkp', output_node_name, "save/restore_all",
        "save/Const:0", 'out/frozen_' + MODEL_NAME + '.pb', True, "")

    input_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    with tf.gfile.Open('out/frozen_' + MODEL_NAME + '.pb', "rb") as f:
        input_graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

    output_graph_def = optimize_for_inference_lib.optimize_for_inference(
            input_graph_def, input_node_names, [output_node_name],
            tf.float32.as_datatype_enum)

    with tf.gfile.FastGFile('out/opt_' + MODEL_NAME + '.pb', "wb") as f:
        f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())

    print("graph saved!")

def main():
    if not path.exists('out'):
        os.mkdir('out')

    input_node_name = 'input'
    keep_prob_node_name = 'keep_prob'
    output_node_name = 'output'

    x, keep_prob, y_ = model_input(input_node_name, keep_prob_node_name)

    train_step, loss, accuracy, merged_summary_op = build_model(x, keep_prob, y_, output_node_name)
    saver = tf.train.Saver()

    train(x, keep_prob, y_, train_step, loss, accuracy, merged_summary_op, saver)

    export_model([input_node_name, keep_prob_node_name], output_node_name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**ERROR**

```js
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-2015e0ea466d> in <module>()
    136 
    137 if __name__ == '__main__':
--> 138     main()

<ipython-input-2-2015e0ea466d> in main()
    131     saver = tf.train.Saver()
    132 
--> 133     train(x, keep_prob, y_, train_step, loss, accuracy, merged_summary_op, saver)
    134 
    135     export_model([input_node_name, keep_prob_node_name], output_node_name)

<ipython-input-2-2015e0ea466d> in train(x, keep_prob, y_, train_step, loss, accuracy, merged_summary_op, saver)
     67     print("training start...")
     68 
---> 69     mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
     70 
     71     init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

/anaconda3/envs/nlpTFnltk/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py in read_data_sets(train_dir, fake_data, one_hot, dtype, reshape, validation_size)
    247     raise ValueError(
    248         'Validation size should be between 0 and {}. Received: {}.'
--> 249         .format(len(train_images), validation_size))
    250 
    251   validation_images = train_images[:validation_size]

ValueError: Validation size should be between 0 and 0. Received: 5000.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the MNIST tutorial code, which is calling `read_data_sets` from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py#L213); note that `validation_size` of 5000 comes from that function's default parameters.  It's expecting to get data from the following files:

```
TRAIN_IMAGES = 'train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz'
TRAIN_LABELS = 'train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz'
TEST_IMAGES = 't10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz'
TEST_LABELS = 't10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz'
```

Normally it would try to download those files if it doesn't find them, but the fact that you're getting a `validation_size` of 0 suggests it isn't doing so.  This wouldn't help you anyway, since you don't want to use the MNIST data.

Even if you rename your train and test files to match the above filenames, your code won't work because the MNIST code is also calling [extract_labels](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py#L77), which has a default parameter `num_classes=10` while you want this to be 50.  Your best bet is probably to get rid of the MNIST import completely and read about how to set up an [input pipeline](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/programmers_guide/reading_data); it's not difficult compared to the stuff you've done already.